# supremum norm and L2 nom

Tags: normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I don't understand why this implies
$$
{(\int_{0}^{1}\ { f^{2} dx})^{1/2} \le (\int_{0}^{1}\ { ||f||^{2} dx})^{1/2} =||f||} 
$$ 
where || || is a supremum norm.
It's from:
http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/REUPapers/Gaddy.pdf (Theorem 3.6)

Comment: Well, it is $f^2\leq \|f\|^2$

Comment: yes,but why $$ {(\int_{0}^{1}\ { ||f||^{2} dx})^{1/2} =||f||} $$

Comment: $$
\left(\int_0^1 a^2\ \mathsf dx\right)^{\frac12} = \left(a^2\right)^{\frac12} = a.
$$